# Thread Dump On JBoss , parked threads keep growing everyday until server becomes unresponsive

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, threadpool

Background : we are Running JBoss EAP 7. We are deploying spring boot applications to it (as war deployments). Everyday the thread number in WAITING (parking) state is increasing by about 400 until the server limit is reached after about 30 days".

The Threads in question all look like the following except with different pool number and waiting condition:

````
pool-339-thread-2" #3023 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001744a800 nid=0x1028 waiting on condition [0x00007fa9f927c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000075781d2f0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None```

Does anyone have any insights into as to why this might be occuring?

Much appreciated.
````

Comment: It looks like you're somehow adding new threadpools/executorservices instead of reusing them. Do you use the ExecutorService API somewhere in your own code? Or do you access spring's TaskExecutor or TaskScheduler directly somewhere?

Comment: Also: do you regularly deploy new wars to it? And do you restart the server after a deployment?

Comment: "It looks like you're somehow adding new threadpools/executorservices instead of reusing them." - that was my thinking as well. However going through the code we are not accessing any of those directly. I am wondering if Spring boot is doing something dodgy when you are deploying it was a WAR?

Comment: "Also: do you regularly deploy new wars to it? And do you restart the server after a deployment?" We do deploy regularly , but even when we do a restart after a deployment it still increases by about 400 a day?